# MySQL Update Query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know it has something to do with the syntax, but I'm looking for a way to do the following:

```
UPDATE modules
SET ServerID = boards.ServerID
FROM boards,modules
WHERE modules.ID = boards.ID
```

this doesnt work. I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE boards,modules
SET modules.ServerID = boards.ServerID
WHERE modules.ID = boards.ID
```

Read MYSQL UPDATE syntax at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

> You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables ....
>
> ```
> UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
> WHERE items.id=month.id;
> ```
>
> The preceding example shows an inner join that uses the comma
>   operator, but multiple-table UPDATE statements can use any type of
>   join permitted in SELECT statements, such as LEFT JOIN.

Comment: You should probably prefix `ServerID` with `modules` to avoid an ambiguous column reference

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE modules
SET ServerID = (SELECT b.ServerID FROM boards b WHERE b.ID = modules.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE modules
INNER JOIN boards
ON modules.ID = boards.ID
SET modules.ServerID = boards.ServerID
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE syntax does not include FROM

FROM is meant for SELECT.

if you want to combine the two:

```
UPDATE modules SET ServerID = (SELECT boards.ServerID FROM boards WHERE boards.ID = modules.ID)
```